# How to prevent Android SpeechRecognizer from making noise after being destroyed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-speech-api

I am using [`android.speech.SpeechRecognizer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer) and am having a problem where it makes a distinctive clang sound even after I've called its `stopListening()`, `cancel()`, and `destroy()` methods.

Here is how I create and destroy the `SpeechRecognizer` in [`MainActivity.kt`](https://github.com/espertus/firefox-voice/blob/c7be0ce62d0f507002501ec0260f1f3a5c8f6b98/android-app/app/src/main/java/mozilla/voice/assistant/MainActivity.kt).

```
private fun startSpeechRecognition() {
    Log.e(TAG, "At start of startSpeechRecognition()")
    if (recognizer == null) {
        recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this)
        Log.e(TAG, "Creating new recognizer: $recognizer")
        recognizer?.setRecognitionListener(Listener())
    }
    val intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
    intent.putExtra(
        RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM
    )
    Log.e(TAG, "Starting listening")
    recognizer?.startListening(intent)
}

private fun closeRecognizer() {
    Log.e(TAG, "At start of closeRecognizer()")
    recognizer?.run {
        Log.e(TAG, "Stopping recognizer: $this")
        stopListening()
        cancel()
        destroy()
        recognizer = null
    } ?: Log.e(TAG, "Recognizer already null")
}
```

Here is my log:

```
E/voice.assistan: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
E/MainActivity: At start of closeRecognizer()
E/MainActivity: Recognizer already null
E/MainActivity: At start of startSpeechRecognition()
E/MainActivity: Creating new recognizer: android.speech.SpeechRecognizer@573d161
E/MainActivity: Starting listening
E/MainActivity: At start of closeRecognizer()
E/MainActivity: Stopping recognizer: android.speech.SpeechRecognizer@573d161
E/SpeechRecognizer: not connected to the recognition service
E/SpeechRecognizer: not connected to the recognition service
E/MainActivity: At start of closeRecognizer()
E/MainActivity: Recognizer already null
```

I am testing the code on a Pixel 2 running Android 10 and am compiling with `minSdkVersion` 21 and `targetSdkVersion` 28.

**Can anyone tell me what I could be doing wrong or if there is a bug in the library?**

I currently have a clumsy workaround where I mute the media audio stream after closing the recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need to call `SpeechRecognizer.cancel()`? According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36590386/13044086) answer calling `SpeechRecognizer.destroy()` may suffice.

Also notice not `connected to the recognition service` error in your log, indicating that something goes wrong in SpeechRecognizer. You may try to remove calling of `cancel()` and check whether the error is gone.